# IP Forwarding question

Tags: privacy

I am starting to learn a bit about TCP/IP and I have a question about IP forwarding.

If someone had access to my home network (WiFi password) what are the possibilities that IP forwarding is being applied to all my network traffic (eavesdropping) even though no other machine has been connected to my home router wireless (or at least visibly connected)?

I would like to understand the risk and possibilities of such scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not see any other devices connected to the router, then these possibilities come to my mind:

1. If the data transfer between your device and the router happens by WIFI, your device is broadcasting radio signals, which can be received by anyone in the range and since they already know the wifi password, they can decrypt it also. you will not find this passive listener as they are not connected to the router. [more information here](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/102587/how-much-information-can-be-gathered-about-a-network-without-connecting)
2. your own device is compromised, so every time you connect it to the network, it forwards traffic elsewhere.
3. Your router itself may be compromised, so that it is forwarding traffic elsewhere.

Analyzing the amount of Risk is up to you as it depends on what and how this WIFI network is used. but if this attacker uses your WIFI network for illegal activities then you are in trouble.